# Cloudera/CDH v6.1.x + Python HappyBase v1.1.0: TTransportException(type=4, message='TSocket read 0 bytes')

Tags: python, hbase, thrift, cloudera-cdh, happybase

> EDIT: This question and answer applies to anyone who is experiencing the exception stated in the subject line: **TTransportException(type=4, message='TSocket read 0 bytes')**; whether or not Cloudera and/or HappyBase is involved.
>
> The root issue (as it turned out) stems from mismatching `protocol` and/or `transport` formats on the `client-side` with what the `server-side` is implementing, and this can happen with any client/server paring. Mine **just happened to be** Cloudera and HappyBase, but yours needn't be and you can run into this same issue.

Has anyone recently tried using the `happybase v1.1.0 (latest)` Python package to interact with `Hbase` on `Cloudera CDH v6.1.x`?

I'm trying various options with it, but keep getting the exception:

```
thriftpy.transport.TTransportException:
TTransportException(type=4, message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
```

Here is how I start a session and submit a simple call to get a listing of tables (using `Python v3.6.7`:

```
import happybase

CDH6_HBASE_THRIFT_VER='0.92'

hbase_cnxn = happybase.Connection(
    host='vps00', port=9090,
    table_prefix=None,
    compat=CDH6_HBASE_THRIFT_VER,
    table_prefix_separator=b'_',
    timeout=None,
    autoconnect=True,
    transport='buffered',
    protocol='binary'
)

print('tables:', hbase_cnxn.tables()) # Exception happens here.
```

And here is how `Cloudera CDH v6.1.x` starts the `Hbase Thrift` server (truncated for brevity):

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_141-cloudera/bin/java [... snip ... ] \
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer start \
    --port 9090 -threadpool --bind 0.0.0.0 --framed --compact
```

I've tried several variations to options, but getting nowhere.

Has anyone ever got this to work?

**EDIT**:
I next compiled `Hbase.thrift` (from the `Hbase` source files -- same `HBase` version as used by `CDH v6.1.x`) and used the Python `thrift` bindings package (in other words, I removed `happybase` from the equation) and got the same exception.

(._.);

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a days worth of working on this, the answer to my question is the following:

```
import happybase

CDH6_HBASE_THRIFT_VER='0.92'

hbase_cnxn = happybase.Connection(
    host='vps00', port=9090,
    table_prefix=None,
    compat=CDH6_HBASE_THRIFT_VER,
    table_prefix_separator=b'_',
    timeout=None,
    autoconnect=True,
    transport='framed',  # Default: 'buffered'  <---- Changed.
    protocol='compact'   # Default: 'binary'    <---- Changed.
)

print('tables:', hbase_cnxn.tables()) # Works. Output: [b'ns1:mytable', ]
```

Note that although this Q&A was framed in the context of `Cloudera`, it turns out (as you'll see) that this was `Thrift` versions and `Thrift` Server-Side configurations related, and so it applies to `Hortonworks` and `MapR` users, too.

**Explanation**:

On `Cloudera CDH v6.1.x` (and probably future versions, too) if you visit the `Hbase Thrift Server Configuration` section of its management U.I., you'll find -- among many other settings -- these:

---

### [image: CDH6.1.x Hbase Thrift Server Configuration U.I.]

Notice that `compact protocol` and `framed transport` are both enabled; so they correspondingly needed to be changed in `happybase` from its defaults (which I show above).

As mentioned in **EDIT** follow-up to my initial question, I also investigated a pure `Thrift` (non `happybase`) solution. And with analogous changes to Python code for that case, I got that to work, too. Here is the code you should use for the pure `Thrift` solution (taking care to read my commented annotations below):

```
from thrift.protocol import TCompactProtocol             # Notice the import: TCompactProtocol [!]
from thrift.transport.TTransport import TFramedTransport # Notice the import: TFramedTransport [!]
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from hbase import Hbase
   # -- This hbase module is compiled using the thrift(1) command (version >= 0.10 [!])
   #    and a Hbase.thrift file (obtained from http://archive.apache.org/dist/hbase/
   # -- Also, your "pip freeze | grep '^thrift='" should show a version of >= 0.10 [!]
   #    if you want Python3 support.

(host,port) = ("vps00","9090")
transport = TFramedTransport(TSocket.TSocket(host, port))
protocol  = TCompactProtocol.TCompactProtocol(transport)
client = Hbase.Client(protocol)

transport.open()

# Do stuff here ...
print(client.getTableNames()) # Works. Output: [b'ns1:mytable', ]

transport.close()
```

I hope this spares people the pain I went through. =:)

**CREDITS**:

- [Here (MapR)](https://mapr.com/support/s/article/How-to-modify-hbase-thrift-client-code-if-Hbase-Thrift-Service-enables-framed-transport-and-compact-protocol?language=en_US) and
- [Here (Blog from China)](http://shzhangji.com/blog/2018/04/22/connect-hbase-with-python-and-thrift/)

Comment: Great work. I was facing a similar issue with 6.2 and was able to solve it with the updates to the `happybase` connection object.

Comment: @NikhilBaby Great. I'm glad you figured out your version of this issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem when I was using `CDH 6.3.2` `HBase` recently. It is not enough to follow the above configuration. Also need to close `hbase.regionserver.thrift.http` and `hbase.thrift.support.proxyuser` in order to connect successfully